# Storing a users name after clicking on a link to display

Tags: django

I'm building a ticketing system using the django framework. Whenever a ticket is filled out and submitted, the support group will go into the support app and see the information on what ticket number, customer name, summary, date created, etc. The ticket number is a link to the details of that ticket. What I would like to do is, whenever a user clicks that link, the ticket is automatically assigned to that user. This helps keeps users from being able to pick and choose which tickets they want to do. The way I have it now is whoever updates the ticket to change the status of the ticket, that person is assigned. I feel my options here with django are limited so if you've got any JS ideas, please feel free to share.[image]

Ticket detail view

```
@group_required('Support')
def ticket_detail(request, pk):
    object = get_object_or_404(Ticket, id=pk)

    context = {
        'object': object,
    }
    return render(request, 'support/ticket_detail.html', context)
```

Model

```
class TicketStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ticket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    property = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    details = models.TextField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(TicketStatus, null=True, blank=True, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'support/images', blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='up_ticket')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you refering to updated_by field of Ticket model you need to add this to your view function:

```
@group_required('Support')
def ticket_detail(request, pk):
   object = get_object_or_404(Ticket, id=pk)

   if not object.updated_by:
      object.updated_by = request.user
      object.save()

   context = {
    'object': object,
   }
   return render(request, 'support/ticket_detail.html', context)
```

This way first user who click link will be assigned to ticket. So user click link, in detail view he is assign to this ticket and after that view return ticket detail page

Comment: No. I must have not been explained very well. I can already get the user by them updating the ticket. What I want is if whenever a user clicks the ticket number link, that user will be assigned automatically.

Comment: I don't get it. You dont have assignee field in you Ticket model. When user click link in this list view he is redirected to ticket detail view? How you assaing user to ticket now?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did have an assigned field until i realized i couldnt figure out how to do what I am asking to do. All I am doing is storing the updated field into the assigned column. In the view tickets view there is a ticket number that the user will click to pull up the ticket detail view

Comment: So you want that the first user who clicked link and is redirected to ticket detail view to be assigned to that ticket? by assing you mean to be set in updated_by field? That exactly what is heppening in my post. i edit it to show full detail view of post.

Comment: Hey, I think that works. Though, when I go back to view all tickets, it doesn't show that it was updated by anyone. Maybe i can figure that part out. Thank you for that. Wasn't much to it

Comment: Oh, wait. If i refresh the page, it shows the assigned person in the view all tickets view. Heck yeah man. Thank you